# what is the option for mysql_real_escape_string() function in newest version of php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have used mysql_real_escape_string() function everywhere in the code but now it is depreciated.  I want know what is greatest option for this function to protect sql injection and i am using object oriented database connectivity but do not want the function which need to call with database connection object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Use `mysqli_real_escape_string();`

Comment: Use prepared  statements (but not emulated prepares), `mysqli_real_escape_string()` is not reliable. It suffers from the same shortcomings as `mysql_real_escape_string()` does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[mysqli_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) if you are using the `mysqli` API.

Or take a good step forward and use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) :) [The URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) commented by @DevDonkey is a great introduction to that.